# Rstan compile error on OS X

Tags: r, macos, stan, rstan

I am having a lot of trouble getting Rstan to work on my OSX setup.  For background info, my system is as follows:

- OSX Yosemite v. 10.10.5
- R 3.2.1 GUI 1.66 Mavericks

Each time I run a stan model in R through R stan, I get the following error (regardless of the model I am running, so the stan code has already been checked for syntax errors)

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! In file included from file32b7b27a829.cpp:465:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/rstan/include/rstan/rstaninc.hpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/rstan/include/rstan/stan_fit.hpp:75:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stan/services/mcmc/run_markov_chain.hpp:5:
/usr/local/include/stan/io/mcmc_writer.hpp:138:23: error: no member named 'is_recording' in 'rstan::rstan_sample_writer'
        if (!recorder.is_recording())
             ~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/include/stan/io/mcmc_writer.hpp:155:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'stan::io::mcmc_writer<model32b75b587019_FamaFrench_COV_estimate_namespace::model32b75b587019_FamaFrench_COV_estimate, rstan::rstan_sample_writer, stan::interface_callbacks::writer::csv, stan::interface_callbacks::writer::messages>::write_adapt_finish<rstan::rstan_sample_writer>' requested here
        write_adapt_finish(sampl
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB file32b7b27a829.cpp 2> file32b7b27a829.cpp.err.txt' had status 1 
>
```

**Other pertinent information**:
I *can* successfully run a test program in PyStan.  This seems to be a problem largely with Rstan.

Can anyone give me any clues as to how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like some brew stuff. If so, run `brew doctor`

Comment: What version of RStan are you using? It looks like you've got an incompatible Stan version inside RStan, which could happen if you're updating the Stan submodule independently of RStan.

Comment: It appears as if you have a conflict between different versions of Stan. It looks for `/usr/local/include/stan/services/mcmc/run_markov_chain.hpp` but it should only be looking for Stan-related packages in the StanHeaders package or the rstan package. Make sure you installed rstan with `dependencies = TRUE` and that your CFLAGS is correctly set in ~/.R/Makevars

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest version of Stan (currently 2.8.0) and have installed Rstan exactly as directed. Whenever I don't do that, I get into trouble!

If that doesn't/didn't work: have you tried the Stan user group? They might have more people competent to answer this question.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/stan-users